# Yum - How to stop dependency installs if pretrans scriptlet fails

Tags: rpm, yum

I have RPM spec with multiple dependencies in requires section but I want to fail the rpm and dependencies install if a certain service is running in the system.

I have tried to use pretrans in RPM spec and even though scriptlet is failed, dependencies are still getting installed.

```
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Pre Check if service is running
Service is Already Available on this box .Aborting the installation. 
error: %pretrans(perlTestBase-5.6.7.SNAPSHOT-1.2.201807101630.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PRETRANS scriptlet in rpm package perlTestBase-5.6.7.SNAPSHOT-1.2.201807101630.x86_64
  Installing : php-pear-HTML-Template-IT-1.3.0-2.el5.noarch                                                                                                                                                                                                               1/2 
  Verifying  : php-pear-HTML-Template-IT-1.3.0-2.el5.noarch                                                                                                                                                                                                               1/2 
  Verifying  : 
  perlTestBase-5.6.7.SNAPSHOT-1.2.201807101630.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                    2/2 

Dependency Installed:
  php-pear-HTML-Template-IT.noarch 0:1.3.0-2.el5                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Failed:
  perlTestBase.x86_64 0:5.6.7.SNAPSHOT-1.2.201807101630
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1):

RPM dependencies are statically resolved against packages registered in a database before an installation transaction (where scriptlets are run) is undertaken. There is no current means to fail a transaction depending on dynamic state such as whether a daemon is currently running.

There is also no means to not install dependencies of a package with a failing scriptlet.

Comment: Thank you for your response Jeff.